# New ArrayList filtering from another ArrayList using a String as Filter

Tags: arraylist, filtering

In my program, a `Die` (dice for embroidery) is a class with different fields. One of them is of the type `String` and it is called `haveIt`. So, if the user of the program enters the word "Yes" on the `haveIt` field, he should be able to track a list of all the `Dies` he has, on the `myInventory` list.

How do I do this? Should I create the `myInventory` `ArrayList<Die>` on the fields and constructor of my `Contoller` class or should I built it inside a special method in that class?

I have tryed everything and nothing works. But I am really new on this.

Here is my last attempt, creating a loop to create the new `ArrayList<Die>` (that has "Yes" on the `haveIt` field) from a special `getMyInventory` method in my `Controller` class:

```
public ArrayList<Die> getMyInventory(Die anyDie) {
    for (int counting = 0; counting <  
diesBigList.Count ; counting++); 
        {
        if 
(((Die)diesBigList[counting]).doIHaveIt.contains("Yes")) 

myInventory.add(diesBigList[counting]);

            return myInventory; 
        }   
}
```

It does not compile. It tells me that the result should be an `Array` type but it is resolved as `ArrayList`... (and I do not comprendo that).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a return statement. What if this is never true?

```
if (((Die)diesBigList[counting]).doIHaveIt.contains("Yes"))
```

you never reach your return statement

Here is the answer

```
public ArrayList<Die> getMyInventory(Die anyDie) {
 ArrayList<Die> myInventory = new ArrayList<Die>();
    for (int counting = 0; counting <  diesBigList.Count; counting++) {
        if (((Die)diesBigList[counting]).doIHaveIt.contains("Yes")) {
               myInventory.add(diesBigList[counting]);
        }   
    }
            return myInventory; 
 }
```

Also there could be a problem with this: `diesBigList.Count` I have no idea where you got that object or what it's methods looks like but I presume in my code your making that call correctly.

Comment: Hi, Bnjmn. I thought myInventory.add(diesBigList[counting]) was doing that function. Do you mean that I should write this instead:

Comment: `if(((Die)dieBigList[counting].doIHaveIt : null)...` and then keep the rest of it?

Comment: I got the .Count from an example on StackOverflow. I was trying to adapt it to my code, but I do not have that method created... I think my example does not help... If you where trying to do the new ArrayList filtering with a String, how would you do it?

Comment: Thanks, Bnjmn. I think I learned how to properly make a question on StackOverflow. I am going to create a new one.